# How to configure the root_path to a specific show view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Do you know how we can param the root_path to display the first Post of the current user ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Devise, you can use this function :

In your Application controller:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  @post = current_user.posts.first
  request.env['omniauth.origin'] || post_path(@post)
end
```

It's gonna redirect the user to his first post show